# Using 2 PSU on 1 computer ( Second PSU turns itself off when under load)

Tags: power-supply

I have followed the guides on the internet, in short to start the second PSU short the green wire on P1 with a black ground wire and the PSU will start.

This works, my second PSU does start. But if i attach any harddrives to it it turns itself off after 1-2 seconds. If i only connect fans or nothing it will remain running.

If it mathers the PSU is from colermaster. They're both ATX powersupplies, and i have tried to use 2 different ( But same brand/model)  PSU as the second PSU.

Comment: My quick recommendation would be to avoid all of this by buying a much larger single power supply.

Comment: Nobody has 1k watt powersupplies in stock around where i live. would also be fun to this just for the geek fun

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just jumping it out, you could try [this](http://www.performance-pcs.com/catalog/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=34_186&products_id=21193) adapter cable.

Comment: It shutting off under load sounds like a loose connection or bad PSU to me.  I have this configuration working at my house.